# Code-Suggesting editor for Arduino

Tags: software-development, text-editor, ide, code-review, lint

I use officially recommended code editor **Android Studio** for writing programs with **Android**. And, the most important feature of *it*, which made me more productive is its code-suggestions.

Now, I'm new to Arduino, and the official IDE seems worst to me since it doesn't provide any code suggestions, doesn't warn me if I didn't put semicolons at line end. All it shows at the compile time, which is very frustrating to me.

Is there any IDE for Arduino which provides, **code-suggestions/lint**  features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Programino** - it supports Code Auto-Complete and has more awesome features.

https://programino.com/ide-for-arduino.html

If you're not ready to pay, you can use Microsoft VS Code too. It has a responsive UI and also supports code- autocomplete & Arduino flashing.

https://code.visualstudio.com/

**Update#1**: I think the VS Code has the most relevance in this case.